# Como fazer um select em uma tabela junto com count(*) de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Pessoal hipoteticamente tenho três tabelas (“usuários”, “baralhos” e “cartões”) a tabela “baralhos” está ligada a tabela “usuários” pelo “id_usuário”, por sua vez a tabela “cartões” está ligada a tabela “baralhos” pelo “id_baralho”, sendo assim para cada usuários eu tenho (n) baralhos e para cada baralho eu tenho (n) cartões.

Preciso fazer um select que me traga todos os baralhos pelo id_usuário contendo o (id do baralho), (nome do baralho) e o (número de cartões cadastrado por baralho), a select abaixo quase funciona. Talvez tenha que ultilizar stored procedures fazer um loop para cada baralho

```
SELECT decks.id, decks.name, (SELECT COUNT(cards.id) FROM cards WHERE cards.deck_id = decks.id) as number_of_cards FROM decks LEFT JOIN cards ON cards.deck_id = decks.id WHERE decks.user_id = 29422966;
```

o defeito da select acima é que se tiver 3 cartões ela escreve o baralho 3 vezes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Baseando pelo sua query, tenta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT decks.id, decks.name, COUNT(cards.id) as number_of_cards FROM decks LEFT JOIN cards ON cards.decks_id = decks.id WHERE decks.user_id = 2 group by decks.id order by decks.name ASC
```

Veja se vai funcionar assim

Comment: Acho que é neste caminho, porem esta me retornando somente os dados do primeiro baralho, ela teria que se repetir conforme a quantidade de baralhos e ir alterando pelo id

Comment: Caso não resolva o problema, envia a estrutura das 3 tabelas que esta utilizando assim fica mais fácil de conseguir chegar no que você precisa.

Comment: Exatamente, deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Seria interessante você colocar todas colunas das três tabelas a fim de simplificar e entender melhor ao elaborar a consulta.

Ao meu ver parece uma simples consulta sql que precisa de dados de duas ou mais tabelas, certo?

Caso seja isso, você pode usar o inner join ou left join, ambos conseguem fazer a ligação entre duas ou mais tabelas através da chave primária/estrangeira que constam nas tabelas.

Usando o exemplo de duas tabelas:

```
(table_usuario:
id_usuario (PK),
name)

(table_deck:
id_deck (PK),
id_usuario (FK)
name_deck)
```

Supondo que você queira que a consulta traga o id_usuario, name e o name_deck referente ao id 333, seria assim usando o inner join:

```
select u.id_usuario, u.name, d.name_deck from table_usuario as u
inner join table_deck as d
on u.id_usuario = d.id_usuario
where u.id_usuario = 333;
```

Caso seja necessário a ligação de mais tabelas, você vai acrescentando outros inner joins seguidos sempre do "on" realizando a ligação entre as chaves primarias/estrangeiras.
Em relação ao "Count", você pode adiciona-lo normalmente ao select, da mesma forma que faria em um select simples.

Comment: Exatamente, obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

select d.id, d.name, COUNT(c.id) as num_cartas
from decks d
left join usuario u on d.id = u.id
left join cards   c on d.id = c.deck_id
where u.id = 1
group by d.id, d.nome

Comment: Exatamente, obrigado!